# How to Generate rsa keys using specific input numbers in openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa

I selected 2 prime numbers `p` and `q`.
Calculated public pair: `(n,e)` and private key: `d`.
For ex.

> p = 17, q = 11, n = 187, e = 7 and d = 23

After surfing on the Internet I found this command to generate the public and private key pair :
`openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024`

But I want to generate private key corresponding to `d = 23` and public key corresponding to `e = 7`. How can I give these numbers as input.

Comment: I really don't think openssl supports 8-bit keys

Comment: If it doesn't support 8-bit key than i can generate bigger numbers, but the question is how to use those numbers?

Comment: You can do some coding using openssl/bn.h

Comment: Question is more why you want to use specific input numbers to generator your rsa keys ???

Comment: As far as I know it can be done in code only.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate a DER encoded key using OpenSSL's `asn1parse` command's `-genconf` option.

You'll need to construct an input file for `asn1parse -genconf` to produce an RSA key in the standard format (per [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2)). The syntax for `asn1parse -genconf` is given here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html and indeed, it already has an example for constructing an RSA key.

You need to calculate a few more values (specifically, `d mod (p-1)`, `d mod (q-1)` and `q^-1 mod p`. For the values of `p`, `q`, `d` you gave, these are:

`d mod(p-1) = 23 mod 16 = 7`

`d mod(q-1) = 23 mod 10 = 3`

`q^-1 mod p = 14`

Put this all together into a text file in the appropriate format:

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:rsa_key

[rsa_key]
version=INTEGER:0
modulus=INTEGER:187
pubExp=INTEGER:7
privExp=INTEGER:23
p=INTEGER:17
q=INTEGER:11
e1=INTEGER:7
e2=INTEGER:3
coeff=INTEGER:14
```

To construct the binary DER file:

```
openssl asn1parse -genconf <path to above file> -out newkey.der
```

You can then run this through OpenSSL's `rsa` command to confirm:

```
openssl rsa -in newkey.der -inform der -text -check
```

Which should output:

```
Private-Key: (8 bit)
modulus: 187 (0xbb)
publicExponent: 7 (0x7)
privateExponent: 23 (0x17)
prime1: 17 (0x11)
prime2: 11 (0xb)
exponent1: 7 (0x7)
exponent2: 3 (0x3)
coefficient: 14 (0xe)
RSA key ok
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MBwCAQACAgC7AgEHAgEXAgERAgELAgEHAgEDAgEO
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You can use this to encrypt data with OpenSSL's `rsautl` command (though with this key you're limited to encrypting just a single byte of data providing that byte is also less than 187).

Comment: Just caught me out there for a second: you need `openssl asn1parse -genconf textfile -out newkey.der` where `textfile` is the input file described above.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for a method that requires no other computations from you, than I guess such do not exist.

have a look at rsa_builtin_keygen in [rsa_gen.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c) of openssl source, it generates the primes for itself.

I would suggest you have a look at function `generateKey` [here](https://inventwithpython.com/makeRsaKeys.py) (you will also need the file [cryptomath](https://inventwithpython.com/cryptomath.py) for it to work)