# How to generate RSA CSR vulnerable to ROCA with openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa, csr

I need to generate vulnerable to ROCA RSA CSR ([ROCA vulnerability CVE-2017-15361](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/papers/rsa_ccs17)). Is it possible to do it with openssl and how?

As I understood the point is in modulus, but what kind of modulus it should be and how can I pass it to openssl in generating keypair?

Comment: While there is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850283) to generate a key using user supplied numbers, I am not familiar enough with the specific properties of keys vulnerable to ROCA to provide an example. Perhaps reviewing the code from [this repository](https://github.com/crocs-muni/roca), which tests for ROCA vulnerable keys, might be of use.