# Use a RSA public key to generate the corresponding private key in OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, certificate, rsa, digital-signature

I know that it is possible using [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html) to generate a public and a private key for self-signed certificate in OpenSSL. But for a given Public Key, is it possible for me to figure out the corresponding Private Key? I have been using a 1024-bit RSA public key.

Because I had this question in my homework saying:

Generate a digital signature for the sentence “My name is . My voice is my passport.” that verifies correctly using OpenSSL with the following 1024-bit RSA public key. (Hint: The modulus might not have been generated like a normal RSA modulus.):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCgF35rHhOWi9+r4n9xM/ejvMEs
Q8h6lams962k4U0WSdfySUevhyI1bd3FRIb5fFqSBt6qPTiiiIw0KXte5dANB6lP
e6HdUPTA/U4xHWi2FB/BfAyPsOlUBfFp6dtkEEcEKt+Z8KTJYJEerRie24y+nsfZ
MnLBst6tsEBfx/U75wIBAw== 
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: *"But for a given Public Key, is it possible for me to figure out the corresponding Private Key?"* No, that would defeat the entire purpose of PKI.

Comment: It's possible to brute-force it, though it would take *some* time.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how to brute force for a given private key? @zerkms

Comment: @AakankshaChoudhary it was a joke, sorry - it would take thousands years, unless RSA is broken earlier.

Comment: Brute force hack of 1024 bit RSA seems very, very unlikely. See this answer on Stack Overflow's sister site Information Security Stack Exchange: 
 https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19057/123722

Comment: I think you cannot sign using a public key. The whole idea of signature that only a private key holder owns it.

Comment: This is a challenge problem for you to use your brains, as well as the hints that were provided for you (and which you've not fully shared with us), to solve the problem. It is your homework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a very long answer that came together over a long time. It basically comprises 3 different answers, from bottom to top:

1. **Original answer**
   Details how to create a private key from a public key when the two prime factors of the modulus of the public key are known. This is useful in cases where one of the two primes is relatively small, and can be easily factored. The created key is considered valid by OpenSSL if both factors are effectively prime.
2. **Updated answer**
   Describes how to create a valid private key if the modulus of the public key is the product of more than 2 primes that can be easily factored. The created key is technically valid, but OpenSSL will refuse to use it if it considers the number of factors too large for the length of the key.
3. **Final answer**
   Explains how to create a private key from two factors that are not necessarily prime. The created key has issues, but can be successfully used with OpenSSL to sign messages that can be correctly verified with the public key.

<sup>**Disclaimer:** The answers below are the result of a lot of trial and error. I lack the mathematical background to fully understand all the cryptographic operations that are involved, and found a lot of inspiration on [crypto.stackexchange.com/](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).</sup>

---

### Final answer

**Step 1: Derive the primes**
From the public key in the question, we get that these are the values of the key's modulus (`n`) and public exponent (`e`):

**`n`**=`112420265940019545385580931264662691888876377549063413938338239508058300548918731393322848876821656910452908064089039911552450302375557565600923056341141750687524704844725632296552824986371719004485250857447936962589230504662333990648942759862805127715014382377701044586628936249950092121536791020138692688871`
**`e`**=`3`

As noted in the **Updated answer** section below, the modulus (`n`) is the product of the following 6 prime numbers (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5` and `p6`):

**`p1`**=`55685342628135644993`
**`p2`**=`55929779616155790098563170377`
**`p3`**=`64741922158863007611093686267`
**`p4`**=`1004116810002299452628120005391`
**`p5`**=`899999049528188671493567437865381261`
**`p6`**=`616948235298561636059669351367929995833009266650461846821351961247854078133359796107391322920088709996730585706342033417954132775239823879192156129555584368164353183`

Again, as explained in the **Updated answer** section, it is possible to create a valid multi-prime RSA key from these six values, but OpenSSL will balk at it because it considers a 1024-bit 6-prime key to be insecure. What we will do instead is create a factor `p = p1 * p2 * p3 * p4 * p5`, and a factor `q = p6`:

**`p`**=`182219932739763270648005503629318079241230129119477190482462876894226401750770169792056565873199604072837331844075265147007599647331896874871737`
**`q`**=`616948235298561636059669351367929995833009266650461846821351961247854078133359796107391322920088709996730585706342033417954132775239823879192156129555584368164353183`

Note that `p` is not prime, but that `p` and `q` are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).

**Step 2: Calculate the private exponent and coefficient**
As described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13242), we should be able to calculate a private exponent `d` if we calculate Euler's totient with knowledge of all the prime factors, so in our case, the totient of `n` becomes `ϕ(n) = (p1 - 1) * (p2 - 1) * (p3 - 1) * (p4 - 1) * (p5 - 1) * (p6 - 1)`, or:

**`ϕ(n)`**=`112420265940019545383562082841557623794401803174962816591163564637337152649071389308753109740365619997953228173075041437232667728900367883549436497816570558785205895886262651863610175301779522497901539098790868823740777076877485036802521497522424439611149854943994123031116549292726779873714088471603368345600`

Using the same methods outlined in the **Original answer** section, we calculate the private exponent (`d`) and the coefficient (`c`) to be:

**`d`**=`74946843960013030255708055227705082529601202116641877727442376424891435099380926205835406493577079998635485448716694291488445152600245255699624331877713705856803930590841767909073450201186348331934359399193912549160518051251656691201680998348282959740766569962662748687411032861817853249142725647735578897067`
**`c`**=`11400012284752460027886253528293202304825202012135117091563382077917535900107285161280123288750670147288021587359790762214264926835198334744338`

**Step 3: Create the private's key ASN.1 structure:**

Again, following the same steps described in the **Original answer**, we create a file called `asn` with the following contents:

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:rsa_key

[rsa_key]
version=INTEGER:0
modulus=INTEGER:112420265940019545385580931264662691888876377549063413938338239508058300548918731393322848876821656910452908064089039911552450302375557565600923056341141750687524704844725632296552824986371719004485250857447936962589230504662333990648942759862805127715014382377701044586628936249950092121536791020138692688871
pubExp=INTEGER:3
privExp=INTEGER:74946843960013030255708055227705082529601202116641877727442376424891435099380926205835406493577079998635485448716694291488445152600245255699624331877713705856803930590841767909073450201186348331934359399193912549160518051251656691201680998348282959740766569962662748687411032861817853249142725647735578897067
p=INTEGER:182219932739763270648005503629318079241230129119477190482462876894226401750770169792056565873199604072837331844075265147007599647331896874871737
q=INTEGER:616948235298561636059669351367929995833009266650461846821351961247854078133359796107391322920088709996730585706342033417954132775239823879192156129555584368164353183
e1=INTEGER:137214246688368010854170162309899042235002625091403895801341918066238559668552121536780346376812813096497808976793391993049835618280391164843955
e2=INTEGER:411298823532374424039779567578619997222006177766974564547567974165236052088906530738260881946725806664487057137561355611969421850159882586128104086370389578776235455
coeff=INTEGER:11400012284752460027886253528293202304825202012135117091563382077917535900107285161280123288750670147288021587359790762214264926835198334744338
```

**Step 4: Create the private key**
Using the same commands as in the **Original answer**, we end up with the following private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Running `openssl rsa -in private.pem -inform pem -check -noout` reveals a couple of problems with this private key, which we will quietly ignore:

```
RSA key error: p not prime
RSA key error: d e not congruent to 1
```

**Step 5: Testing the private key against the original public key**
The original question asks to use the created private key (stored in `private.pem`) to sign a message, and then verify that message using the public key from the question (stored in `public.pem`).

To create a signature in file `signature` of the message passed in via standard input:

```
echo "My name is Robby. My voice is my passport." | openssl dgst -sign private.pem -keyform pem -sha1 -out signature
```

To verify the signature against the same message:

```
echo "My name is Robby. My voice is my passport." | openssl dgst -verify public.pem -keyform pem -sha1 -signature signature
```

Which yields:

```
Verified OK
```

Mission accomplished.

---

### Updated answer

The original answer below started from the assumption that the modulus (`n`) is the factor of two primes `p` and `q`. When I tried to factor `n`, after finding one factor `p`, I readily assumed that the remaining `q` was also prime.

This is not the case, which renders the answer below, as well as the created private key, invalid. While it will generate a matching public key, signature verification (or decryption) will fail when using the key pair for signing (or encryption).

I have decided to leave the **Original answer** up because it does correctly show how to create a private key for cases where the modulus actually is the factor of two primes, and can be easily factored.

As far as a correct and complete answer to the original question goes, I am only partway there: I have now factorized `n` to the following 6 factors, which (as far as I can tell) are all prime:

**`p1`**=`55685342628135644993`
**`p2`**=`55929779616155790098563170377`
**`p3`**=`64741922158863007611093686267`
**`p4`**=`1004116810002299452628120005391`
**`p5`**=`899999049528188671493567437865381261`
**`p6`**=`616948235298561636059669351367929995833009266650461846821351961247854078133359796107391322920088709996730585706342033417954132775239823879192156129555584368164353183`

Using some of the mechanisms outlined in the original answer, it is possible to create a *multi-prime* RSA key consisting of these 6 prime numbers. The ASN.1 structure to pass to `openssl asn1parse` would look like this:

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:rsa_key

[rsa_key]
version=INTEGER:1
modulus=INTEGER:112420265940019545385580931264662691888876377549063413938338239508058300548918731393322848876821656910452908064089039911552450302375557565600923056341141750687524704844725632296552824986371719004485250857447936962589230504662333990648942759862805127715014382377701044586628936249950092121536791020138692688871
publicExponent=INTEGER:3
privateExponent=INTEGER:74946843960013030255708055227705082529601202116641877727442376424891435099380926205835406493577079998635485448716694291488445152600245255699624331877713705856803930590841767909073450201186348331934359399193912549160518051251656691201680998348282959740766569962662748687411032861817853249142725647735578897067
prime1=INTEGER:55685342628135644993
prime2=INTEGER:55929779616155790098563170377
exponent1=INTEGER:37123561752090429995
exponent2=INTEGER:37286519744103860065708780251
coefficient=INTEGER:10583113183442869648
otherPrimeInfos=SEQUENCE:other_prime_infos

[other_prime_infos]
prime3=SEQUENCE:prime3
prime4=SEQUENCE:prime4
prime5=SEQUENCE:prime5
prime6=SEQUENCE:prime6

[prime3]
prime=INTEGER:64741922158863007611093686267
exponent=INTEGER:43161281439242005074062457511
coefficient=INTEGER:27817376944661773518043380720

[prime4]
prime=INTEGER:1004116810002299452628120005391
exponent=INTEGER:669411206668199635085413336927
coefficient=INTEGER:285320348305749284006046153442

[prime5]
prime=INTEGER:899999049528188671493567437865381261
exponent=INTEGER:599999366352125780995711625243587507
coefficient=INTEGER:658460078383005934070309924158661879

[prime6]
prime=INTEGER:616948235298561636059669351367929995833009266650461846821351961247854078133359796107391322920088709996730585706342033417954132775239823879192156129555584368164353183
exponent=INTEGER:411298823532374424039779567578619997222006177766974564547567974165236052088906530738260881946725806664487057137561355611969421850159882586128104086370389578776235455
coefficient=INTEGER:578350825258330649391070121677654395357069928435806599539320692960806529213345731736785707130093900487154780989433570566819293550718740139056912058574616030960959114
```

However, while OpenSSL will generate this private key, it refuses to use it for signing as it considers 6 primes too much for a 1024 bit key. Theoretically, it should be possible to use another library/tool with support for weak multi-prime RSA keys to sign/encrypt a message using this key, but I have yet to find one.

---

### Original answer

The key (pun intended) to the solution is in the hint:

> The modulus might not have been generated like a normal RSA modulus.

This is the approach I took.

**Step 1: Derive the primes**

1. I first took your file and saved it as `public.pem`.
2. To get the value of the modulus (`n`) and the public exponent (`e`), I ran:
   `openssl rsa -pubin -in public.pem -text -noout`
3. I converted the hexadecimal modulus and exponent to decimal numbers, which yielded
   **`n`**=`112420265940019545385580931264662691888876377549063413938338239508058300548918731393322848876821656910452908064089039911552450302375557565600923056341141750687524704844725632296552824986371719004485250857447936962589230504662333990648942759862805127715014382377701044586628936249950092121536791020138692688871`
   **`e`**=`3`
4. I plugged that number into an [online factorization calculator](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) to discover that one of the two primes used to calculate the modulus was relatively small:
   **`p`**=`55685342628135644993`
   **`q`**=`2018848419246646476894946094575564515176862561629979956283227393349426117194195173357244644821277073710795134539986018769393928719340504755806449531413017314396784334912136112253736003497362080917517151753555605597776865614151048604681116557282512513238254935296910445878892354969335089447`

**Step 2: Calculate the private exponent and the coefficient**

1. I calculated the totient of `n` as `ϕ(n) = (p - 1) * (q - 1)` using the python REPL:
   **`ϕ(n)`**=`112420265940019545383562082845416045411981431454487849423161376946428320592635503999973422759627461737095663419267762837841655167835571546831529127621801245931718255313312614982156040651459582892231514853950574881671713352908778385051165894248654079110333265820418532073390681314653181675602213322541221954432`
2. I then used the python script from [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54479) to calculate the private exponent (`d`) and the coefficient (`c`), which yielded:
   **`d`**=`74946843960013030255708055230277363607987620969658566282107584630952213728423669333315615173084974491397108946178508558561103445223714364554352751747867497287812170208875076654770693767639721928154343235967049921114475568605852256700777262832436052740222177213612354715593787543102121117068142215027481302955`
   **`c`**=`1040291110785843997`
   Here, `d` is calculated as `d ≡ e^−1 mod ϕ(n)` and `c` as `c ≡ q^-1 mod p`.

**Step 3: Create the private key's ASN.1 structure**

I then used the calculated values to create an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) structure in a file named `asn` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19855935/3558960):

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:rsa_key

[rsa_key]
version=INTEGER:0
modulus=INTEGER:112420265940019545385580931264662691888876377549063413938338239508058300548918731393322848876821656910452908064089039911552450302375557565600923056341141750687524704844725632296552824986371719004485250857447936962589230504662333990648942759862805127715014382377701044586628936249950092121536791020138692688871
pubExp=INTEGER:3
privExp=INTEGER:74946843960013030255708055230277363607987620969658566282107584630952213728423669333315615173084974491397108946178508558561103445223714364554352751747867497287812170208875076654770693767639721928154343235967049921114475568605852256700777262832436052740222177213612354715593787543102121117068142215027481302955
p=INTEGER:55685342628135644993
q=INTEGER:2018848419246646476894946094575564515176862561629979956283227393349426117194195173357244644821277073710795134539986018769393928719340504755806449531413017314396784334912136112253736003497362080917517151753555605597776865614151048604681116557282512513238254935296910445878892354969335089447
e1=INTEGER:37123561752090429995
e2=INTEGER:1345898946164430984596630729717043010117908374419986637522151595566284078129463448904829763214184715807196756359990679179595952479560336503870966354275344876264522889941424074835824002331574720611678101169037070398517910409434032403120744371521675008825503290197940297252594903312890059631
coeff=INTEGER:1040291110785843997
```

The values of the two exponents `e1` and `e2` are calculated as `d mod (p - 1)` and `d mod (q - 1)` respectively.

**Step 4: Create the private key**

Based on the ASN.1 structure, I generated the private key as follows:

1. Create the private key in DER format:
   `openssl asn1parse -genconf asn -out private.der`
2. Convert the private key to PEM format:
   `openssl rsa -in private.der -inform der -out private.pem -outform pem`

This results in a `private.pem` file being created with the following contents:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Step 5: Verifying the result**

To check whether the created private key (in `private.pem`) matches the provided public key, I just generated a new public key from the private key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout
```

This yields the following output:

```
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCgF35rHhOWi9+r4n9xM/ejvMEs
Q8h6lams962k4U0WSdfySUevhyI1bd3FRIb5fFqSBt6qPTiiiIw0KXte5dANB6lP
e6HdUPTA/U4xHWi2FB/BfAyPsOlUBfFp6dtkEEcEKt+Z8KTJYJEerRie24y+nsfZ
MnLBst6tsEBfx/U75wIBAw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This output exactly matches the public key that you provided.

Comment: Holy Moly! does that mean RSA encryption is UNSECURE ??

Comment: @crushman not really, as said in the answer the prime number was small

Comment: how did you calculate `e1` and `e2`??

Comment: @thecowmilk I am revisiting this answer now and I think it's incorrect. The value of `e2` doesn't seem right, but what's worse is that I also think that `q` is not prime. I will be updating the answer soon.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen dont think you have made any mistake. I tried and it was correct. the point is that I'm finding a hard time calculating `e1` and `e2` and `coeff`

Comment: btw I did calculate them both now

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hi, how could you find 6 factors of that number?

Comment: @thecowmilk Used a combination of factordb.com and the site linked in the answer. Took less than a day on my very modest laptop.

Comment: @thecowmilk Looks like I finally cracked it. That was decidedly non-trivial :) Thanks for bringing this question back to my attention. It always kind of felt like I had unfinished business here.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you are more than welcomed :) although if you wanna linkup to talk somewhere it would be awesome, ping me and tell me where should we chat(if you want too)