# Generate a private key from public key

Tags: algorithm, certificate, ssl-certificate, rsa, private-key

I am try to generate a private key from rsa public key. My attempts to use the formulas from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053884/use-rsa-public-key-to-generate-private-key-in-openssl) were unfortunately unsuccessful, because the codes never matched. My target is to calculate an RSA 1024 bit private key from this public key.

Edit: I have now added the public key, because the previous one was an entire certificate.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQD1cJDUjO87H/eM+VxtUxB5gHIH
W2Q1wniS6kxXPzaEnPPzaQflsEHOV2mrCnXd2qsa9Soqpl5U0x3OlzjXnaYRfck7
0BsppFRnEFfhPFmXOKxv4pCx30O9O+yAD69Z8h+OGJtL2DQfPpcTuOxxwYS77BfG
rSymPSF0gLFV1mn4AwIBAw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: RSA keys start with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- or -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. Are you sure what you are trying to use is actually an RSA private key?

Comment: If it's a *real* public key, then you won't be able to do that.  If you could, then RSA would be very broken.

Comment: To generate an RSA private key from the public key: step 1, factor the modulus. Step 2: there is no step 2.  For a real RSA 1024-bit key step one will take about 100 million CPU years, per https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70829/how-long-does-it-take-to-crack-rsa-1024-with-a-pc. If it were easier than that, there'd be no use for it. (and RSA-1024 is "too easy to break" by modern standards).

Comment: Those "formulas" only work when the RSA key was generated using a grievously flawed algorithm.  Do you have some reason to suspect that is the case here?

Comment: The file is already 13 years old and probably only uses standard RSA encryption.