# Cont:Use a RSA public key to generate the corresponding private key in OpenSSL?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, sha256

I see this posts [Use a RSA public key to generate the corresponding private key in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053884/use-a-rsa-public-key-to-generate-the-corresponding-private-key-in-openssl) about how to solving the private key from public key, but I still cannot figure it out for this public key:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCC98+XVTxNUDsTutF6jNKjc4jd
kLng6gAKlDd1xg5lhwl2NPqb6VYUIXDsV3Q5hZs6N1xyLkuHAtq4mMETuJG8CC8y
Tqw2j9Yt5xPdbX9WMYqr6mIHiC1GN9Jk5S6sIW+8pCUYhCQWG6yg1sB9cj5aY5UP
2iW6LawXSLUHj2m9JQIBAw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

could you help me finding the private key?

openssl rsa -in ec_key.pub -pubin -text -noout
Public-Key: (1024 bit)
Modulus:
00:82:f7:cf:97:55:3c:4d:50:3b:13:ba:d1:7a:8c:
d2:a3:73:88:dd:90:b9:e0:ea:00:0a:94:37:75:c6:
0e:65:87:09:76:34:fa:9b:e9:56:14:21:70:ec:57:
74:39:85:9b:3a:37:5c:72:2e:4b:87:02:da:b8:98:
c1:13:b8:91:bc:08:2f:32:4e:ac:36:8f:d6:2d:e7:
13:dd:6d:7f:56:31:8a:ab:ea:62:07:88:2d:46:37:
d2:64:e5:2e:ac:21:6f:bc:a4:25:18:84:24:16:1b:
ac:a0:d6:c0:7d:72:3e:5a:63:95:0f:da:25:ba:2d:
ac:17:48:b5:07:8f:69:bd:25
Exponent: 3 (0x3)
ubuntu@cis551:~/project2$

Comment: You **cannot** recover the private key from the public unless there was a significant flaw in the key generation. 1024-bit moduli are not impossible to factor, but they take significant resources.

Comment: There are two possible answers: 1) the key was purposely generated with a weak N => see the answer you refer, 2) the key is generated properly => you can't do it.

Comment: Because I had this question in my homework saying to do that:(

Comment: ok, then perhaps your homework also contains a clue as to what the flaw is in its generation.

Comment: Well, it turns out one of the primes is quite small. That should be enough of a hint.